# convert int16_t into jbytearray

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am using an Native library in android for streaming.

---

Here is the scenario:

I am passing a url to c file and after lot of processing it writes the data in wav file.

I'm not so much familiar with C but what i could understand is there is a pointer of `int16_t` from which wav file is written.

---

Here is the question.

Is there any way to convert `int16_t` to `jbytearray` so that i can return a byte array to my java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate a byte[] and then copy the WAV data into it.  Alternatively, create a "direct" ByteBuffer that spans the WAV data, and pass that into your Java code.

Read the [JNI documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html) and the [JNI Tips](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/jni-tips.html;hb=HEAD) doc for more info.  In particular:

SetByteArrayRegion
  NewDirectByteBuffer

Comment: can you please give some more details on it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the first thing about Android, but you might want to look into `java.nio.ByteBuffer` - they can be made to allocate their buffer in native memory (`allocateDirect()`), so native functions can write directly into it.

Comment: it does not related to java, all my operations needs to be done in **c** code only whether its' about accessing a created variable or to pass it `I Need to convert int16_t to jbytearray` that's essential for me.

Comment: @user503249: *...so that i can return a byte array to my java code.* My answer was an attempt to show you why this might not be necessary: Your C code could write its data directly into the buffer used by the `ByteBuffer` object.

Comment: If possible can you post a sample code? Coz I'm confused by this mixup of c and java code. And i only had some basic knowledge of C ,never done any coding for that. :-(